# nginx return corrupted data from memcached

Tags: nginx, memcached

On my web site i've made data caching with memcached. It stores fully generated html pages. Next step was to get this data from memcached by nginx and send back to user w\o starting apache process.
First i tried to get data from cache by php backend and it worked. But when i try make this with nginx - i see hardly corrupted data. smth like https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFGW0.png

i'm asking for help with this problem.

p.s. here the part of nginx config if it can help

```
location / {
    #add_header    Content-Type  "text/html";
    set $cachable 1;

    if ($request_method = POST){
        set $cachable 0;
        break;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~ "beauty_logged") {
        set $cachable 0;
        break;
    }

    if ($cachable = 1) {
        set             $memcached_key   'nginx_$host$uri';
        memcached_pass  127.0.0.1:11211;
    }

    default_type    text/html;
    error_page      404 502 504 405 = @php;
    #proxy_pass http://front_cluster;
}

location @php {
    proxy_pass http://front_cluster;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nginx does not process the content stored in Memcached, it just gets it and returns to the browser as is.

The real cause is the Memcached client library your application uses. Most of the libraries compress large values (usually when value size exceeds some threshold), so you must configure it not to do so, or set [`memcached_gzip_flag`](http://nginx.org/r/memcached_gzip_flag) with [gunzip module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html) enabled.